# How to receive/ accept Bluetooth serial data on ESP32 using NimBLE bluetooth library

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth, serial-port, esp32

```
    #include "NimBLEDevice.h"

// void setup() in Arduino
void app_main(void)
{
    NimBLEDevice::init("NimBLE");
    
    NimBLEServer *pServer = NimBLEDevice::createServer();
    NimBLEService *pService = pServer->createService("ABCD");
    NimBLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic("1234");
}
```

I want to show/print the string sent to esp32 over the Bluetooth serial. I am using the NimBLE library in the esp32. But I don't know how to accept/receive data coming over Bluetooth serial using NimBLE. How to do with  NimBLE.

Comment: I am not using classic i am only using  Nimble

Comment: Not 100% sure which functionality you need, but the library you are using does have an examples folder. This would be a [BLEClient example](https://github.com/h2zero/NimBLE-Arduino/tree/release/1.4/examples/NimBLE_Client) from that library.